# .NET Core Multi Tenant localhost is null after setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant

I am trying out the Finbuckle multi tenant library now and have managed to set the tenant information for the user.

However, when I redirect to another page and load the tenantinfo in the view, it shows up as null. Am I doing something wrong?

This is how I get and set my tenantinfo:

```
var OrganizationId = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(xc => xc.Type == MultiTenancy.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.OrganizationId).Select(xc => xc.Value).SingleOrDefault();
var tenantInfo = await store.TryGetByIdentifierAsync(OrganizationId);
HttpContext.TrySetTenantInfo(tenantInfo, resetServiceProvider: true);
var ti = HttpContext.GetMultiTenantContext()?.TenantInfo;
return RedirectToAction("Sample", "Home", new { __tenant__ = tenantInfo.Name });
```

This is the Sample View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Sample";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var tenantInfo = Context.GetMultiTenantContext()?.TenantInfo;
}
@using Finbuckle.MultiTenant.AspNetCore

<h2>@tenantInfo.Name</h2>
```

EDIT:

So far what works is if I do this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Sample()
{
    var OrganizationId = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(xc => xc.Type == MultiTenancy.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.OrganizationId).Select(xc => xc.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    var tenantInfo = await store.TryGetByIdentifierAsync(OrganizationId);
    HttpContext.TrySetTenantInfo(tenantInfo, resetServiceProvider: true);
    var ti = HttpContext.GetMultiTenantContext()?.TenantInfo;
    return View(ti);
}
```

But that means that the tenantinfo has to always be set. Is there a way to make it persistent?

This is my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMultiTenant()
    .WithEFCoreStore<MultiTenancyDbContext, TenantInfo>()
    .WithDelegateStrategy(context => {
        var organizationId = ((HttpContext)context).User.Claims.Where(xc => xc.Type == MultiTenancy.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.OrganizationId).Select(xc => xc.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        return Task.FromResult(organizationId);
    });



app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pinging me over on the GitHub site for [Finbuckle.MultiTenant](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/issues/172).

The reason the tenant information is lost is because the Redirect to Action redirects the user browser so its like an entirely new HTTP request which basically resets everything. The second approach you posts doesn't actually redirect the user browser so it doesn't lose the info. Finbuckle.MultiTenant should work with either approach--I'll try to clarify how it works below.

It looks like you are setting the tenant info yourself, but while this is possible it is not the intended flow. The library was designed so that its middleware would use a strategy, query the store, and set the tenant info before your controller code is ever hit. It would look something like this (where `WithStrategy` and `WithStore` are simplified for this example):

```
// In your services configuration in your Startup class:
services.AddMultiTenant().WithStrategy().WithStore();

// In your app pipeline in your Startup class:
app.UseMultiTenant(); // <-- This sets the tenant info
```

So in normal situations you don't need to call `store.TryGetByIdentifierAsync(...)` or `HttpContext.SetTenantInfo(...)`.

Instead you want to define a strategy that gets the organization ID from the cookie like you did. The middleware will use the strategy at the start of every request to set the tenant info. There is a `DelegateStrategy` that should work for your situation. It requires you to set a delegate or lambda that will return the tenant identifier, in your case the organization id:

```
services.AddMultiTenant().WithStore().
         WithDelegateStrategy(context =>
         {
             var organizationId = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(xc => xc.Type == MultiTenancy.ClassLibrary.Globals.CookieGlobals.OrganizationId).Select(xc => xc.Value).SingleOrDefault();
             return Task.FromResult(organizationId);
         });
```

Please check out the [delegate strategy sample](https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/tree/master/samples/DelegateStrategySample) in the repository to see a working project that uses a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this! Your delegatestrategy worked. I just have another question, I'm still getting ?__tenant__= in my urls. Is it possible to remove them?

Comment: I added my Startup.cs with the delegation to the question. It seems to work but only the _tenant_= parameter is left

Comment: In your route setup in Startup do you have anything about the tenant there? If so, remove it--it's intended for use with the route strategy, but you're not using that strategy now.

Comment: I removed the WithRouteStrategy section and also the app.useMvc(route.MapRoute(name:"tenant",template: "{tenant:exists}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}"));

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: I'm trying to make this work with my area. So far it seems like my url is always https://localhost:44332/Dashboard?Identifier=00cd58f8-61cb-4900-ba2e-c6e052748e3a

Comment: Your routes look good. Are the urls generated coming out ok? What about for the areas? Can you post the Razor or code that generates the URLs? At this point the issue probably isn't related to Finbuckle.MultiTenant, but I'm happy to try to help.